# how to stop scanning when input is null (scan an unknown number of ints)

Tags: c, scanf

I'm currently working on a program that scans each int and finds out if it is perfect or not. The problem is, I do not know how many ints there are in the input, so I want to find out how to stop scanning when the input ends.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int input[500], count;
  for (count = 0; count < 500; count++) {
    scanf("%d", &input[count]);
    if (input[count] == 0)
      break;
  }

  for (count = 0; count < 500; count++) {
    if (findFactors(input[count]) % input[count] == 0)
      printf("%d perfect\n", input[count]);

    else if (findFactors(input[count]) % input[count] <= 2 ||
             findFactors(input[count]) % input[count] >= input[count] - 2)
      printf("%d almost perfect\n", input[count]);

    else
      printf("%d not perfect\n", input[count]);
  }
}
```

In this case, I need to enter 500 numbers for the code to run. I need it to run when the input is null. I know there is '/0' or something but I don't know how to use it in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a function read the [doc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

In return value

> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

So you need to check the return value of scanf:

```
if (scanf("%d", &input[count]) != 1)
  break;
```

Comment: what exactly do I have to enter for the code to run? i tried this but the code didn't run.

Comment: @DanielToh "what exactly do I have to enter for the code to run?" i write it you need more ? "i tried this but the code didn't run." "didn't run" is not very useful information. http://cpp.sh/5dlx you can try yourself (option => standard Input => text)